# getline() and reading data from text files

Tags: c++

The program I code below should 
List all payment made by each student, show amount paid and outstanding

I need some help with the following section:

```
void payment()
{
    // Display message asking for the user input
    std::cout << "List all payment made by each student, show amount paid and outstanding." << std::endl;

    // Read from text file and Display list of payment

    std::ifstream infile;               // enable to open, read in and close a text file
    float StudentCode;                  // to store the student enrolment number
    float Amount;                       // to store the amount of money
    float Type;                         // to store information on type of payment made
    float Outstanding;                  // to store amount of money is due

    infile.open("Payment.txt");         // open a text file called Payment

    if (!infile)                 
    {
        std::cout << "Item list is empty" << std::endl;     // if the file is empty it output the message
    } 
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "List of Payment: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enrolment No." << "Amount" << "Outstanding" << std::endl;

        // If there is Student Code that has the same number, it need to combined the amount it paid 
        // For an example 
        // Student Code: 12 Amount: 25
        // Student Code: 12 Amount: 50
        // so it should display the following when the program runs:
        // Student Code: 12 Amount: 75

        while(!infile.eof())            // output the description of the text file onto the screen
        {
            getline(infile,StudentCode,Amount);

            Outstanding = Amount - 100;

            std::cout << StudentCode << Amount << "$" << Outstanding << std::endl;
            //iter++;
        }
        std::cout << "End of list\n" << std::endl;
    }

    infile.close();         // close the text file  
}
```

What is wrong with the getline part:

```
getline(infile,StudentCode, Amount);
```

Also the program should not display repeated Student Code but combine the amount it paid.
Where I explain in the comment section

```
// If there is Student Code that has the same number .....
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The getline part is pretty easily answered by googling the API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2whx1zkx(v=vs.71).aspx

getline reads characters, not floats.

Comment: Do **not** use `eof()` to detect that reading is complete: it does **not** work that way. Instead, **always** check **after** reading that your attempt to read input was correct. Where did you get the idea from that `eof()` should be used? If it is a book, please let us know the title; if it is from your teacher, please tell your teach to stop teaching this nonsense!

Comment: When I use getline in the past, I use eof() for some reason. Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) reads a line from a stream into a string. What you're trying to do, is more like this

```
while (infile >> StudentCode >> Amount) {
    // process values
}
```

If you want to sum up all amounts, you must first accumulate and afterwards loop through the collected values and print them

```
std::map<int, float> amountsPaid;
int studentCode;
float amount;
// accumulate amounts
while (infile >> studentCode >> amount) {
    amountsPaid[studentCode] += amount;
}

// loop through map and print all entries
for (auto i = amountsPaid.begin(); i != amountsPaid.end(); ++i) {
    float outstanding = i->second - 100;
    std::cout << i->first << ": " << i->second << "$, " << outstanding << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help out about the program should not display repeated Student Code but combine the amount it paid. 
If there is Student Code that has the same number, it need to combined the amount it paid 
For an example 
Student Code: 12 Amount: 25
Student Code: 12 Amount: 50
so it should display the following when the program runs:
Student Code: 12 Amount: 75 rather than repeating it both

Comment: @user1582575 See modified answer. First collect values, then print all.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. One is that `getline` reads one line of text into a single `std::string` variable, not multiple `float` fields.

For that you might try

```
infile >> StudentCode >> Amount;
```

A second problem is that

```
while(!infile.eof())
```

will not check if the next input is going to work but if the *previous* input attempt failed beause it reached end-of-file.

The standard method is to combine these into

```
while (infile >> StudentCode >> Amount)
{
    // do something with the code and amount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to getline doesn't seem correct.

The documentation states

```
istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim );
```

But your giving it

```
getline(istream&, float, float);
```

You should be trying to read the line as a string and then parse out the 2 floats.

Since your using c++, if the file is well formatted you could just redirect cin and it'll be easier. You could just do something like

```
while (infile >> StudentCode) {
  infile >> Amount;
}
```